# What is the theoretical difference between method with type parameter and generics method type parameter declaration

Tags: java, generics

Hi all i am learning Generics in Java. in which i have created this hierarchy.[image]

Now i have created a `LivingThing` class

```
public class LivingThing<T extends LivingThingTypes> implements Iterable<LivingThingTypes>{
public ArrayList<T> create(Class<T> type) {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T item : list) {
            if (item.getClass().equals(type)) {
                arrayList.add(item);
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

So when i try to access `create()` method like this code of section it doesn't works.

```
livingList.create(Human.class).size();
livingList.create(Cat.class).size();
livingList.create(Hen.class).size();
```

But if i change method into this it works perfectly

```
public class LivingThing<T extends LivingThingTypes> implements Iterable<LivingThingTypes>{
        public <V extends LivingThingTypes>ArrayList<V> create(Class<V> type) {
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (T item : list) {
                if (item.getClass().equals(type)) {
                    arrayList.add(item);
                }
            }
            return arrayList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how it is off topic, it is programming question.

Comment: I think your problem actually might have to do with shadowing of T, although I'm not sure. In the first can you try renaming the T from your function declaration to a V, so you don't have two Ts in scope (T extends LivingThingTypes and the T of the arraylist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing about generics is that they are invariant. This means in your case that even though Human class extends `LivingThingTypes` but `List<Human>` doesn't extend `List<LivingThingTypes>`. So basically you can't do the following assignment:

```
List<Human> list1;

List<LivingThingTypes> list2 = list1; //compile error
```

That's how Generics are designed. The reason is imaging you have a Animal parent class and Dog and Cat as child classes. Now you created a `List<Dog>` and assigned it to `List<Animal>`. Now Since Animal is parent class of Cat also you can add cats to `List<Animal>`. Wile iterating it may give `ClassCastException`. Now the basic pros of using Generics is they provide Type safety but getting `ClassCastException` means that is not the case and thus the Generics are invariant.

But when you use extends along with Type parameter then it allows the assignment but then you have to remember [PECS(Producer Extends and Consumer Super)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723538/6407858).

In your first case you have Type Parameter  declared at class level.  Now when you create instance of LivingThing class you have to mention the type parameter like `LivingThing<LivingThingTypes> livingList = new LivingThing();`. And that becomes the value of T. Now the compiler will expect you to send the same Type inside create method also because of the reason I mentioned in the earlier para.

In your second case you are creating a new Type parameter which is bound to the method only and here you are telling it that `V extends LivingThingType` and thus now `Class<V>` type argument of create method can accept `Human.class/Hen.class/Cat.class`. You can use the same Type parameter T also in place of V but to avoid confusion you should name them differently as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

That was not working because of this concept defined in Java-Oracle-Docs.

[image]

**(As Java Doc Says)**
Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and Integer), MyClass has no relationship to MyClass, regardless of whether or not A and B are related. The common parent of MyClass and MyClass is Object.